# Detect HBase cluster health

Tags: hbase

I have 2 HBase clusters and I want to read from a cluster which is healthy. (anyone if both are healthy)

I am currently on HBase version: 2.2.3.7.1.7

Is there any API that I can hit and find the health of HBase cluster ?
For e.g. the health can be in terms of number of Region Servers up and running.

I am using Java to connect to HBase and HBaseAdmin class does not provide any such utility.

Is someone aware of any way (I would prefer any REST API call if possible else any other way) to detect HBase cluster's health ?

I want to know the HBase health before making the real query so that my request is served in time and not stalled due to HBase health issues.

Comment: The region server should already tell you this information, but using Prometheus JMX exporter might be a better option for collecting data from the cluster overall